# Как заставить логировать python скрипт в режиме демона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, логирование

Есть программа, написанная на Python, которая логирует исключения в файл, с помощью стандартного модуля logging. Запускаю в Ubuntu 18. Всё замечательно работает, логи записываются в файл. Но. Как только я запускаю скрипт как сервис, с использованием systemctl, логирование отваливается. При этом, во всём остальном скрипт стабильно работает в режиме демона(кроме работы с электронной почтой, но это уже тема отдельного вопроса)

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы логирование работало так же, как и в случае обычного запуска?

Comment: Вы проверяли, что у процесса, запущенного через systemctl, есть доступ на запись в нужный файл/каталог?

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо за наводку. Я проверил вашу гипотезу. Действительно, для всех, кроме владельца были выставлены права только на чтение. Я сделал chmod 666 на файл и перезапустил демона. К сожалению, логи так и не записываются

Comment: Что насчёт прав на все родительские каталоги? И от имени какого пользователя запускается процесс через systemctl?

Comment: Выставил права на все родительские каталоги 777. systemctl запускается через sudo. sudo выполняется из под отдельного пользователя. Папка с кодом и логами соответственно принадлежит отдельному пользователю, не руту

Comment: `sudo`? Судо в юните системд? А можно полный листинг файла сервиса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ведь логи можно писать в журнал:

```
import logging
from systemd.journal import JournalHandler
level = logging.INFO
handlers=[JournalHandler()]
logging.basicConfig(level=level, handlers=handlers)
```

И смотреть их `journalctl -u yourproject.service` или `journalctl --user -u yourproject.service`